# Why hydrostatic pressure only depends on height from the surface to object?

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics

Why hydrostatic pressure depends on the height from the surface to the object? I know that the formula-- $pgh$ shows that it depends on the height; what is the reason?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trouble deriving hydrostatic pressure equation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/309669/)

Comment: @Chemomechanics It does partially. But why it doesn't depend on the volume of fluid? Two containers of same height but one is narrow and the other broad should exert different pressures. I am able understand the derivation but I also require a theoretical explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The pressure is defined as a force applied perpendicular to a surface

$$p = \frac{F_\perp}{A}$$

Imagine a column of height $h$ and base area $A$ full of fluid of density $\rho$. Assuming everything is static, the total force on the column base equals force of air pressing down on fluid surface plus force of column of fluid pressing down on the column base

$$F_\perp = F_a + F_f$$

Force of column of fluid equals fluid weight in that column

$$F_f = m g = \rho V g = \rho A h g$$

The (static) pressure at the column base is then

$$p = \frac{F_a}{A} + \rho g h$$

Note that the term $F_a/A$ equals air pressure outside the column, and the above equation becomes

$$\boxed{p = p_a + \rho g h}$$